# What is the difference between hiding title in xml or via java code?

Tags: android, xml, themes, hide, title

(I dont know if its related but I want to use custom theme in my app.) Which should I use and why(performance issue, simplicity etc)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no real difference.

You can choose what best suits your needs.

If you know you'll want the title to be hidden in every activity of your application then the best solution is to set a theme for the whole application in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file

`<application android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">`

Of course you can change `@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar` to your custom style.

Comment: I'm a newbie on stackoverflow so I do not have enough reputation to vote it up. if I could, I would...